# HTML 5: #Header or <header>

Tags: html

I am a little confused now by html so i've a question about the  semantic element:

Should i use  like this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="main-header">
        <!-- menu and imaganary logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Demo</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Or this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-header">
        <!-- menu and imaganary logo -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Demo</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I read http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/ about the header element. It tells that it usefull for the headings of a `<article>`
It doesn't give me information about this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<header>` is also good for the page header or for a `<section>`'s header not just for articles. You can use both your examples without a problem. I recommend you use `<header>` for easier readability.

Comment: Agree, seems logical to use `<header>`: "a group of introductory or navigational aids. A header element typically contains the section’s heading (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element), but can also contain other content, such as a table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos." http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML Specification

> The `<header>` element is intended to usually contain the section's heading (an `<h1`>-`<h6>` element or an `<hgroup>` element), but this is not required. The  element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.

So, you should probably go with the first example, although the second one too can be used without a problem.
Also you can directly use the header element in your CSS like below.

```
header {
    // style the header
}
```